# how to calculate poles of a discrete line in python api?

Tags: python

Is there any `python libs` that could calculate poles of a line like `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)...]?`

for instance, I have a line consist by `2d points` like `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]...]`, then I want to calculate the poles of the line, only using `python libs`. So is there any `python lib` could do this for me

[image]

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. By "line" do you mean the graph of a function, as in your diagram? What is a "pole" of such a line? Just how is the "line" determined by the given points? (Infinitely many functions could include those points). Finally, asking for a library is explicitly off-topic for this site.

Comment: LINE: refer to discrete point (x,y) data list.
poles: is local and global maxima and minima points

Comment: You did not answer how the function (with its graph) is determined by the given points. There are infinitely many functions through those points, each possible function with its own maxima and minima.

Comment: while, the points I mentioned here is random, but is not infinitely. what I wanna do is figuring out the poles of those discrete points. for instance, here I have 6 points, for simple, i only change the y value, x value keeping increasing:[[0,0],[1,0.5],[2.0.25],[3,1.5],[4,1.0],[5,0.5]], then, the poles excepting the origin [0,0] is [1,0.5], [2,0.25], [3, 1.5]... However, I do not want do this by myself. So, my question is "is there a python lib could help me do this thing"

Answer (score 1):

**Hello HOWE,**

Python provides many library for the create the any types of the graph.
For example 2d, 3d,... graph etc.

## 1. NumPy

---

If you use `Math` function/expression so first install this library it is provides many easy functionality.

NumPy is the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python. It contains among other things:

- a powerful N-dimensional array object
- sophisticated (broadcasting) functions
- tools for integrating C/C++ and Fortran code
- useful linear
  algebra, Fourier transform, and random number capabilities

Besides its obvious scientific uses, NumPy can also be used as an efficient multi-dimensional container of generic data. Arbitrary data-types can be defined. This allows NumPy to seamlessly and speedily integrate with a wide variety of databases.

Install this library for go on this link, http://www.numpy.org/

## 2. Matplotlib

---

After install this library to create the any types of the graph.

Matplotlib is a Python 2D plotting library which produces publication quality figures in a variety of hardcopy formats and interactive environments across platforms. Matplotlib can be used in Python scripts, the Python and IPython shell, the jupyter notebook, web application servers, and four graphical user interface toolkits.

Install this library for go on this link, https://matplotlib.org/

**I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.**